# Google Maps API -- works in IE9, FF, Chrome, but not in IE7 & IE8

Tags: maps

I've done my due diligence, checking for additional commas, trying to see if I was improperly calling the script, but I can't seem to find why my google map is failing in IE 7 & IE 8.

The error the IE console is throwing is..

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'elementType': object
>   is null or undefined  %7Bcommon,map,util,marker,infowindow%7D.js, line
>   2 character 1

When I look into the error more specifically it calls out a line of google's code and says it doesn't work.

Has anyone experienced this issue? And any recommendations for how to solve it?

url - discoverplanon.com

Comment: There appears tohave been an error in the way I applied a blue overlay for map styling. I've removed the code so the error isn't live, but will need to resolve still.

Comment: mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'map_style']
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          myOptions);
var styles = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      {hue: '#006699'},
      {saturation: '80'}
    ]
  },
]
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"});
map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');